# How to user setInterval in firebase functions?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-tasks-api

I´m trying to use a setInterval inside a firebase function to run for 40 minutes then stop. Since the max timeout for onCall function is 9 minutes what workaround could be used?

I saw a suggestion to use [GCP tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks) but didn´t was able to find how I could make use of it in this context

Even if I would need to run a timeout to run 40 minutes later, how this could be done with GCP tasks?

Answer (score 1):

For this case an option is to create a HTTP Target task and put it in a task queue. Basically, you will schedule something to call your Cloud Function when you want. There is no way to keep the function alive for more than 9 minutes, but, instead of that, Cloud Tasks would call it again and again when you want. 
[Here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks) you can find the official documentation guide of achieving that. Keep in mind that, as it is stated in the official documentation:

> Timeouts: for all HTTP Target task handlers the default timeout is 10 minutes, with a maximum of 30 minutes.

Honestly, for your use case, my recommendation would be to use forget about Cloud Functions and think more of using [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/) or [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/). I think they would be more suitable.

Comment: Hy there @AndreiTigau. I'll test your recommendations. Thanks for take the time of answering!